# Trouble concatenating two strings

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I am having trouble concatenating two strings. This is my code:

```
info = infl.readline()
while True:
    line = infl.readline()
    outfl.write(info + line)
    print info + line
```

The trouble is that the output appears on two different lines. For example, output text looks like this:

```
490250633800 802788.0 953598.2
802781.968872 953674.839355 193.811523 1 0.126805 -999.000000 -999.000000 -999.000000
```

I want both strings on the same line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There must be a `'\n'` character at the end of `info`. You can remove it with:

```
info = infl.readline().rstrip()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove line breaks in the line and info variables like this :
`line=line.replace("\n","")`

Answer (score 1):

`readline` will return a "\n" at the end of the string 99.99% of the time. You can get around this by calling `rstrip` on the result.

```
info = infl.readline().rstip()
while True:
    #put it both places!
    line = infl.readline().rstip()
    outfl.write(info + line)
    print info + line
```

readline's [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.readline):

> Read one entire line from the file. A trailing newline character is kept in the string (but may be absent when a file ends with an incomplete line)...

Comment: +1 for 99.99%, but -1 for suggesting the rstrip in the wrong place.