# Why is a new line being created when concatenating strings

Tags: python

I'm trying to open a file, and edit a specific line. When I concatenate a character onto one of the lines, it works, but inserts a new line. However I don't want a new line. Here is the code:

```
def moveCurlyInline(line, i):
    with open('test.js', 'r') as inputFile:
        data = inputFile.readlines()
        print(data[0])
        print(data[0] + ' {')
```

The print outputs:

```
function hello()
```

then:

```
function hello()
 {
```

I need the curly bracket to be on the same line as the function hello. Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Because every string in your list ends with a newline. Did you try printing the `repr`?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12330535/532978). Basically, when you use `inputFile.readlines()` the output has newline characters on the end of every line.

Comment: Ok i'll check it out, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trouble concatenating two strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084937/trouble-concatenating-two-strings)

Comment: try `print(data[0].strip() + ' {')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`f.readline()` reads a line from the file, **including the newline** at the end of the line.

Try stripping the extra newline:

```
data = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in inputFile]
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can strip new line character by

`inputFile.read().striplines()`